# How to see data posted in python-mechanize

Tags: python, http-post, mechanize

I want to see what parameters is posting in python-mechanize. What I tries is:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> import cookielib
>>> url='http://mywebsite.com/login'
>>> br=mechanize.Browser()
>>> cj=cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
>>> br.set_handle_robots(False)
>>> br.set_handle_refresh(False)
>>> br.set_handle_equiv(True)
>>> br.set_handle_referer(True)
>>> br.set_handle_redirect(True)
>>> br.set_cookiejar(cj)
>>> br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(),max_time=1)
>>> br.addheaders=[('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14')]
>>> site=br.open(url)
>>> br.select_form(nr=0)
>>> br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
>>> br.form['username']='UserName'
>>> br.form['password']='Password'
>>> br.submit()
```

As you see I try to login to my account. How can I see the data that is posting with `username` and `password`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? Entire http request being sent?

Comment: No...I want other post parameters posting to my server... For example: `username='username'&password='password'&token='exampleToken' `and etc. when you login to site user name and password with some other data is posting... I want data posted to server